# Query Paginated XML via REST API using Power Query

Tags: jquery, xml, api, powerbi, powerquery

I am getting this error: Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation.
I think it's on this line: = Table.FromList(DataList, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)

I was using the Advanced Web input in PowerBI, but the API limits requests to 100 records per query.

```
let 
    BaseUrl = "https://api.samanage.com/incidents.xml",
    Token =  [TOKEN],
    EntitiesPerPage = 100,
    Options = [Headers=[Accept="application/vnd.samanage.v2.1+xml", #"X-Samanage-Authorization" = "Bearer " & Token ]],
    Url = BaseUrl,

    GetXml = (Url) =>
        let
            RawData = Web.Contents(Url, Options),
            xml = Xml.Document(RawData)
        in
            xml,

    GetTotalCount = () =>
        let
            Xml = GetXml(Url),
            Entities = Xml(EntityCount)
        in
            Entities,

    EntityCount = GetTotalCount(),
    PageCount = Number.RoundUp(EntityCount / EntitiesPerPage),
    PageIndex = { 1 .. PageCount},

    GetPage = (PageIndex) =>
        let
            PageUrl = BaseUrl & "page=" & Text.From(PageIndex),
            Xml = GetXml(PageUrl),
            Value = Xml[ticket_metrics]
        in
            Value,

    GetUrl = (PageIndex) =>
        let
            PageNum = "page=" & Text.From(PageIndex),
            PageUrl = BaseUrl & PageNum
        in
            PageUrl,

    Urls = List.Transform(PageIndex, each GetUrl(_)),
    Pages = List.Transform(PageIndex, each GetPage(_)),
    DataList = List.Union(Pages),

    TableFromList = Table.FromList(DataList, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
in
    TableFromList
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run your code, so I might be totally wrong and way off in what I write below, but I think inside of your `GetTotalCount` function, you may have meant to write:

```
Entities = Xml[EntityCount]
```

instead:

```
Entities = Xml(EntityCount)
```

I'm assuming (but I may be wrong) that there is an `EntityCount` field in the XML resource you're working with.

---

Regarding the cyclical error, if we take this line:

```
EntityCount = GetTotalCount(),
```

and then look inside `GetTotalCount`, we see that it cyclically refers to `EntityCount`

```
GetTotalCount = () =>
    let
        Xml = GetXml(Url),
        Entities = Xml(EntityCount)
    in
        Entities,
```

---

Unrelated: Generally, if you want to get some data from an API, but aren't sure from the outset how many requests it will take, you can use something like `List.Generate` which will continue to generate a list of values (in your case, these values might be sequential API responses) and you can give it a function to define when it should stop.

Details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-generate.